# Can complex number cancel out, as in $\frac{(3+2i)\cdot(1+i)}{(1+i)} = 3+2i$? If so, can I use that idea in complex differentiability?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, complex-numbers

Can complex number cancel out? For instance, is the following statement true? $$\frac{(3+2i)\cdot(1+i)}{(1+i)} = 3+2i$$

If so, given a complex function $f:C\to C$, if I were to determine if it is complex differentiable (if 
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}= a+bi$$ for some $a,b\in R$, where $h$ is a complex number, then it is), could I cancel out the $h$ appearing in the numerator and denominator for any complex polynomial in the same method as performing first principle on real numbers?

Edit to clarify: For instance, for $f(z) = z^2$, I have 
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(z+h)^2-z^2}{h}= 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{z^2+2z\cdot h-h^2-z^2}{h}= 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2z\cdot h-h^2}{h}=
2z+\lim_{h \to 0} h=2z
$$

Comment: yes, you can "cancel" any number as long as it is non-zero. In your example, $1+i \neq 0$ so you can "cancel" it. For your second question, I'm not sure what you're asking. What does $f$ being differentiable at $z_0$ have anything to do with cancelling $h$? and how does a polynomial come into the picture?

Comment: We don't often get to completely cancel $h$ out top and bottom when taking a derivative of a real-valued function of real numbers. Perhaps you mean something different than I think when you write "cancel out". It might help if you edit the question to show an explicit example of an expression "before" and "after" canceling the $h$ so we can see what you mean.

Comment: edited to clarify with example

Comment: @DavidK sorry for mentioning again but I added an example and am wondering if the computation sequence is valid.

Comment: @user64742 I ask because there is a question my professor gave us and his hint was to change h->0 into (a,b)->0 and "use the meaning of complex division"

Comment: @user64742 Using the definition above and the complex function $f(z) = z^2$, compute f′(z) at z = x + iy.
Hint: Write it out with h = a + ib, and let (a, b) → (0, 0). Use the meaning of complex division above to help you. It will be messy but keep focus. Finally, polar coordinates may help you take the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {f(z+h) - f(z)}{h}$

$h$ has a real part and a complex part. i.e. $h = x+iy$

Similarly $f$ has a real and complex part.

$f(z) = u(z)+ iv(z)$

Making these substitutions our difference quotient becomes:

$\frac {u(z+x+iy) + iv(z + x+iy) - u(z)- i v(z)}{x+iy}$

We could rationalize the denominator by multiplying by the conjugate of $h,$ but it makes things a little messier than they need to be.

$\frac {xu(z+x+iy) - xu(z) + yv(z+x+iy) -yv(z) - ixu(z+x+iy) + iu(z) + iyv(z+x+iy) - iyv(z)}{|h|^2}$

Instead, suppose we consider small movements in the real direction separately from movements in the y direction. i.e. let $x$ be small while setting $y=0$

$\lim_\limits {x\to 0} \frac {u(z+x) - u(z)}{x} + i\frac {v(z+x) - v(z)}{x} = \frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}$

And then consider small movements in the imaginary direction (setting $x$ equal to $0$, and $y$ small but non-zero).

$\lim_\limits {y\to 0}\frac {u(z+iy) -u(z)}{iy} + \frac {iv(z+iy) -iv(z)}{iy} = \frac {1}{i} \frac {\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac {\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y} - i\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$

And a general movement of $h$ is just a combination of movements in the real part and the imaginary part.

Here is the real trick, though.

If the function is complex differentiable, then the derivative is the same for all small movements in $h$!

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac {\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y} - i\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$

IF they are equal the real parts are equal and the imaginary parts are equal

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}\\
i\frac {\partial v}{\partial x} = - i\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$

These are called the "Cauchy-Riemann equations."  And a function is complex differentiable iff it satisfies these equations.

Example:

$f(z) = z^2 = (x+iy)^2 = x^2 - y^2 + i(2xy)\\
u(z) = x^2-y^2\\
v(z) = 2xy\\
\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac {\partial v}{\partial x} = 2y = -\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$

All polynomials are complex differentiable, as are functions that can be represented as a polynomial.  i.e. they have a Taylor Series, and you are evaluating within the radius of convergence of the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

If $h$ is a complex number $a+bi$, $h$ can be cancelled out in the computation of the derivative so long as $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$, i.e. $0+0i.$

Let's demonstrate what would happen if we didn't cancel the $1+i$; i.e we expand the denominator, and then multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate...

$$(3+2i)(1+i) = 3 + 5i - 2 = 1 + 5i$$

$$\dfrac {1+5i}{1+i} = \dfrac {(1+5i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)} = \dfrac {6+4i}{2} = 3+2i$$

Same number, just a little more work.

Comment: Thanks! What about the second part? Is my example a valid computation sequence?

Comment: I've corrected my post.  Yes, your computation sequence is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since literally

$$ \frac{2z\cdot h-h^2}{h} = 2z - h $$

for any complex $h\neq 0,$ yes, you can "cancel" the $h$ as follows:

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2z\cdot h-h^2}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} (2z - h), $$

and then since each of the limits $\lim_{h \to 0} 2z$
and $\lim_{h \to 0} h$ is finite, you can proceed as you did in the question.